# Bash: not evaluating variable correctly

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have a simple bash function which includes a loop to capture hostnames for x number of times (defined in $number_of_hosts):

```
number_of_hosts="3"

for i in $(seq 1 $number_of_hosts); do 
    read -ep "enter hostname" host$i
done
```

If I echo out each variable individually they work.  For example

```
echo $host1
echo $host2
echo $host3
```

However, if I try to add another for loop around that (used in a later function), I can't seem to get it to work.  I am using

```
for i in $(seq 1 $number_of_hosts); do 
    echo $host$i
done
```

How can I successfully echo the values that were captured by 'read' earlier?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't use variables like that. Also have you use a `$` in the declaration of `number_of_hosts` ? You also only have one `done` in the second bit, but i'll assume that it is intentional :)

Comment: yes, sorry I left some of my code in there.  updated to remove.  do you know how i could use that variable correctly?  is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few grimy ways to use "variable variables" but I wouldn't recommend them. Why not just use an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

number_of_hosts=3
for i in $(seq 1 "$number_of_hosts"); do 
    read -ep "enter hostname" 'host[i]'
done

echo "${host[1]}"
echo "${host[2]}"
echo "${host[3]}"
```

If you want to avoid calling `seq`, you can also change your loop:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= number_of_hosts; ++i )); do
    read -ep "enter hostname" 'host[i]'
done
```

Comment: yes, this worked great, thank you! I used the variable in the next for loop as `echo "${host[$i]}"`

Comment: Taking this one step further, is there any way to read these variables from another bash file which have the variables defined as the same names ... i.e.`host1="abc"  host2="def"` ...and then load it in the display function `for i in $(seq 1 $number_of_hosts); do 
 echo -en "${host[$i]}" done`   Is that possible?  I tried to source the file before the loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, are there several files or just one? It seems like this is becoming a separate question - rather than changing the scope of this one or polluting the comments, perhaps it would be worth asking a new question, so you can provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

 number_of_hosts="3"

 for i in $(seq 1 $number_of_hosts); do
         read -e -p "enter hostname: " host[$i]
 done

 for item in ${host[@]}; do
         echo $item
 done
```

The point is, `host` is an array in this case, which perfectly fits your needs. The next important thing is the variable `number_of_hosts` - when you declare the variable in Bash, you write just its name. The dollar sign is written only if you want to get its value.